# Align label from left and right that have "\n"

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have one label with text like this

```
label.text = "A    34\nB    11\nC    4\nD    3"
```

it look like this

```
A      34
B     11
C       5
D    3
```

---

Is there a way to align label from left and right so it look like:

```
A      34
B      11
C       5
D       3
```

Comment: What about using `\t`?

Comment: NSAttributedString seems to be able to do that.

Comment: I get my text from database, so it's dynamic, how i know the right space to add ??

Answer (score 0):

`You could make a row Class (custom UIView) and have each "column" element (separate UILabel) set by the data used to populate it. You could then have a table Class so that you could use the longest string and adjust the positioning of the each column. This approach would give you a lot of control, but extra work.

Or use NSAttributedString with tab stops.

```
let myText = "A\t34\nB\t11\nC\t5\nD\t3"
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: NSTextAlignment.Left, location: 150, options: [:])]
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 150
label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes:[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle])
```

You can calculate the longest string width in a loop to determine what the `headIndent` should be. However, this wouldn't allow for the right column to be right-aligned like in your example. You would get something like:

```
A        34
B        11
C        5
D        3
```